# Trace32 - command lock on sys.gtl

Tags: trace32, lauterbach

I am trying to debug a A53 and hexagon core.

I have attached the A53 core, which is now running. But when i run the hexagon core, I get **command locked** in SYS.GTL.LIBNAME "&GTLPATH\&GTLDllName" both the variables are substituted.

```
       SYS.GTL.MODELNAME "model_name"
        SYS.GTL.GPIONAME "GPIO_name"
        SYS.GTL.LIBNAME "&GTLPATH\&GTLDllName"
        cd "&DllPath"
        SYS.GTL.CONNECT
        cd "&currdir\.."
        SYS.CONFIG.DAPNAME "dapname"
```

I have this config in startup.cmm of both a53 and hexagon cores.

But when I debug by stepping the cmm script, I am able to pass through the line and i am not facing any errors.

Is there any other config I am missing.

Answer (score 1):

You have to execute the `SYStem.GTL.LIBNAME` command on both GUIs before any of them executes `SYStem.Up` or `SYStem.Attach`.

Comment: I tried it but I get debug hardware configuration error in the second core . stating that dll is not found

Comment: In this case I think you should contact the Lauterbach support hotline https://www.lauterbach.com/tsupport.html